# How do I show crisp lines in a UniformGrid control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make a uniform grid with each cell with a border (much like if I had used a standard Grid and set ShowGridLines property to true).  I have seen a variety of example that show how to do this but none of the render crisp lines.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this has to do with aliasing. You may want to look into these properties:

- [RenderOptions.EdgeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I cannot give you any specifics right now as i despise lines and thus have no such issues.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  I played around with SnapsToDevicePixels but I didn't know about EdgeMode.  I'll give it a go then report back.

Comment: The answer, as it turned out was to set SnapsToDevicePixels="False", RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified" and the Border's Width="0.5".  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad this worked out even though could just provide pointers. :)